# Firefox sound sometimes playing static noise 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, firefox, pulseaudio, alsa

The thing is sometimes when I'm watching videos on youtube or wherever firefox has a delay in audio followed by static noise.This applies to firefox only, if I play a movie or something it works properly. Rebooting the system fixes the problem but still it gets annoying. And also while the firefox is open sometimes I can hear a tiny bit of noise coming from the speakers like someone is hitting a table with a finger, a little (tup) every now and then. I'm curious if anyone has similar experience and ultimately a fix for this. I did try to reinstall complete audio but still it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: https://tqdev.com/2021-firefox-ubuntu-crackling-sound

Go to about:config in Firefox and search for "media.webspeech.synth.enabled" and set it to "false" (double clicking on the entry should do it) then close Firefox. Don't forget to restart Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problems on both of my Ubuntu 20.04 machines, so you are not alone.. so far the only thing that has helped me a little is tinkering with PulseAudio Volume control.. (I particularly had static audio noise when changing output to HDMI, PulseAudio fixed that for me, and I have a constant gentle background clicking when volume is high on my desktop, through headphone speakers, from when I upgraded to 20.04..)